# Update Ember model live via action

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and keep struggling on a simple task. My goal is to achieve live update of the page content after action is triggered. I'm quite lost in Ember logics regarding route-controller-model relationship in this case.

So my `template.hbs` is something like:

```
<h1>{{model.somedata}}</h1>
<button {{action 'getContent'}}>Get Content</button>
```

My controller accepts some params from user form and makes the AJAX call:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    somedata: 'hello',
    actions: {
        getContent: function () {
            var self = this;

            Ember.$.ajax({

                // ... standart call with some query data

                success: function(result) {
                    self.set('somedata', result);
                } 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My route model returns only controller params, so if I get it right as controller properties get updated, there must be a simple step to update the current model and display all changes to the template.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return params;
    }
});
```

Can you guys give me a tip how this process is regularly built in Ember?

Comment: Are you looking for "this.controller.set('somedata', result)"?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this, but in this case model will not be updated

Comment: Try "this.currentModel.set('somedata', result)"

Comment: So far I've used an overkill setting controller properties as call result, so I can access them lively in the template, but I'm confused as I do not retrieve my template data from model, but from controller directly. This ember logics makes me confused more and more

Comment: You are looking for `self.set('model.somedata')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `self.set('model.somedata', results)`.

Your code as it stands is setting the `somedata` property on the controller, which doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Thanks, will try this)

Comment: @markoffden That is the entire purpose in life of Ember.

Comment: and if my action is in route (as controller purpose is actually not for those), I'm getting data via ajax call and want to update model. In my template there is something like {{ model.shout }}, and route action does something like self.set('model', {'shout': 'hello'}), I still do not get any updates in the template.

Comment: The route does not have a model property, and normally updating the model is something that would and should be done in the controller. The route is for, well, routing-related things, and the controller is for, well, controlling-related things.

Comment: thanks, but still I'm doing something wrong and do not get live updates

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's a bit confusing, here's how I think of it...

First Ember sets up the route.

The route has multiple **hooks** that are used to get and process the model (i.e. beforeModel, model, afterModel).  Ember will always look for these as part of it's opinionated nature.

There is also a setupController hook that will fire after all the model hooks.  As part of the setupController hook, the controller will be created and the model will be passed to the controller.

Once that happens, I've found it helpful to think of the model as no longer being part of the route, but the controller instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to consider this, you made it a bit more clear to me

Comment: It would be more technically correct to say *There is also a `setupController` hook that will fire after all the model hooks, and after the controller is created. Usually (and this is the default behavior) this hook populates a `model` property on the controller with the resolved value of the model*.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers will be deprecated. So IMO **do not use controllers**.

Handle that action in your route. If you bind value to the object returned by model hook, your data and page will be updated when you update the value.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    somedata: null,
    model: function(params) {
        return { 
           params: params,
           somedata: this.get('somedata')
        };
    },
    actions: {
        getContent: function () {
            ...
            var _this = this;
            ...
            success: function(result) {
                _this.set('somedata', result);
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion))